# Make: "error: missing separator", no matter the indentation

Tags: makefile

```
` 875 # $1: boot image target
 876 # returns the kernel used to make the bootimage
 877 define bootimage-to-kernel
 878         @echo "test"
 879   $(if $(BOARD_KERNEL_BINARIES),\
 880     $(PRODUCT_OUT)/$(subst .img,,$(subst boot,kernel,$(notdir $(1)))),\
 881     $(INSTALLED_KERNEL_TARGET))
 882 endef`
```

Adding line 878 causes "build/make/core/Makefile:2326: error: missing separator."

This is the line at 2326:
`$(foreach b,$(INSTALLED_BOOTIMAGE_TARGET), $(eval $(call add-dependency,$(b),$(call bootimage-to-kernel,$(b)))))`

I have tried every form of indentation I can think of, including commenting it out, but only completely removing it prevents the error.

Comment: I presume that this enormous makefile was generated by something like automake. Editing generated makefiles is usually a waste of time. Like all generated code they are notoriously difficult to reverse-engineer and modify, and even if you get it working the way you like, there's no way to back-propagate the change to whatever you fed to the generator.

Comment: Definitely not automake.  The goal of automake is to provide a facility to write a "simplified" makefile.am that autoamake turns into a makefile that can be used by standard POSIX make.  So if you see lots of GNU make functions in it it's almost certainly not automake generated.  This looks more like the Linux kernel build environment.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information to let us help you.  We don't know what the user-defined macros `add-dependency` expands to, and we don't know the context of the text you show from line 2326: is it in a recipe?  Or by itself on the line?

You are modifying the value of `bootimage-to-kernel` as if it were a recipe, by adding recipe commands like `echo test` into it.  But probably it's NOT a recipe so that makes no sense.  If it IS in a recipe, then you've broken it by adding a newline and not indenting the next line (line 879).

The right way to debug issues with `eval`, is to duplicate the rule but replace the `eval` with the `info` function.  This will cause make to *print out* the text that it would evaluate.  You can then see what make is trying to evaluate and see what the problem is.

For example if line 2326 is just this (not part of a rule):

```
$(foreach b,$(INSTALLED_BOOTIMAGE_TARGET), $(eval $(call add-dependency,$(b),$(call bootimage-to-kernel,$(b)))))
```

then change the `eval` to `info` like this:

```
$(foreach b,$(INSTALLED_BOOTIMAGE_TARGET), $(info $(call add-dependency,$(b),$(call bootimage-to-kernel,$(b)))))
```

and see what make prints.  It will probably be obvious why adding that line breaks everything.